# how to move selected item in a list using up and down arrow keys in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement up and down arrow buttons for a list in HTML. the up arrow moves the selected element of list upwards and the down arrow moves the selected list element downwards. I tried this code, but not working ::

```js
function reorder_up(node) {
  $(".go_up").click(function() {
    var $current = $(this).closest('li')
    var $previous = $current.prev('li');
    if ($previous.length !== 0) {
      $current.insertBefore($previous);
    }
    return false;
  });
}


function reorder_down(node) {
  $(".go_down").click(function() {
    var $current = $(this).closest('li')
    var $next = $current.next('li');
    if ($next.length !== 0) {
      $current.insertAfter($next);
    }
    return false;
  });
}


// for adding to the result page i am using this function, where i am creating a list dynamically and provinding the id to the selected element when clicking on it. I need to move up - down in the result section of the list :: 


function add_to_result() {
  //var moparent = document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML;
  var moname = document.getElementById("moselect").innerHTML;
  var node = document.createElement('LI');
  node.setAttribute('onclick', 'giveid_Result(this)');
  node.setAttribute('ondblclick', 'fillprops()');
  var text = document.createTextNode(moname);
  node.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("result").appendChild(node);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class='go_up' onclick="reorder_up(this)" style="height:40px;width:40px">&uarr;</button>

<button type="button" class='go_down' onclick="reorder_down(this)" style="height:40px;width:40px">&uarr;</button>



<div id="results">
  <div class="boxheader">
    <STRONG>RESULTS</STRONG>
  </div>
  <div class="boxcontent">
    <ul id="result">

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `$(".go_up").click` and `$(".go_down").click` from functions or remove the functions and only attach events in javascript.

Comment: Also if you want to use `closest('li')` then the buttons will need to be inside `li` element not outside.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var  selected;
 for(var x=0;x<5;x++){
        addToResult("Node:"+x);
    }
$("li").click(function(){
  console.log("pressing"+$(this).attr("id"));
  select($(this))
});
$(".go_up").click(function(){reorder_up(selected)});
$(".go_down").click(function(){reorder_down(selected)});
function reorder_up(node) {
 var dnode=node;
   console.log("RUP");
    var $current = $(dnode).closest('li')
    $current.css("background-color","blue");
    var $previous = $current.prev('li');
    $previous.css("background-color","yellow");
    if ($previous.length !== 0) {
      $current.insertBefore($previous);
    }
    return false;
  
}


function reorder_down(node) {
  console.log("RDO");
  var dnode=node;
    var $current = $(dnode).closest('li')
    $current.css("background-color","blue");
    var $next = $current.next('li');
    $next.css("background-color","yellow");
    if ($next.length !== 0) {
      $current.insertAfter($next);
    }
    return false;
  
}


// for adding to the result page i am using this function, where i 
//am creating a list dynamically and provinding the id to the selected 
//element when clicking on it. I need to move up - down in the result section of the list
// :: 


function addToResult(id) {  
  var node = document.createElement('li');
  node.setAttribute('id',id);
 // node.setAttribute('onclick', 'select(id)');
  node.setAttribute('ondblclick', 'fillprops()');
  var text = document.createTextNode(id);
  node.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("result").appendChild(node);
}
function select(selector){
  selector.css("background-color","green");
  console.log("youre pressing"+selector.attr("id"));
  selected=selector;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class='go_up'  style="height:40px;width:40px">&uarr;</button>

<button type="button" class='go_down' style="height:40px;width:40px">&darr;</button>



<div id="results">
  <div class="boxheader">
    <STRONG>RESULTS</STRONG>
  </div>
  <div class="boxcontent">
    <ul id="result">    
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The $(something).click query executes when you click on that something. So it doesn't make sense to put into a function. You want it to trigger some function execution. 
I added the dnode var to keep the scope of the node since this is no longer attached to the node when you call reorder node. So I substituted **this** with **dnode** and it works fine. Here is the fully working  [code](http://codepen.io/Castanon/pen/JGQrwq?editors=1010):

Javascript:

```
for(var x=0;x<5;x++){
    add_to_result("Node"+x);
}
$("li").click(function(){      
   select($(this))
 });

$(".go_up").click(function() {
 reorder_up(selectedNode);
  });

  $(".go_down").click(function() {
      reorder_up(selectedNode);
  });

    function reorder_up(node) {
    var dnode=node;
    var $current = $(dnode).closest('li')
    var $previous = $current.prev('li');
    if ($previous.length !== 0) {
      $current.insertBefore($previous);
    }
    return false;

}


function reorder_down(node) {
    var dnode=node;
    var $current = $(node).closest('li')
    var $next = $current.next('li');
    if ($next.length !== 0) {
      $current.insertAfter($next);
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can remove the onclik attribute from html. It is not needed

About the add to result function: There is no element with the **moselect** id, so **moname** is null and the compiler gives an error. Next, you never call it so it will never execute. You should add a loop somewhere to add the elements. You don't need to set attribute **onclick**, just use a jquery
selector.I added set attribute **id** to pass it to select function. By the way, I don't see **give_id** function anywhere so I created a function to **select** the node to be moved

```
function add_to_result(id) {  
  var node = document.createElement('li');
  node.setAttribute('id',id);
  node.setAttribute('ondblclick', 'fillprops()');
  var text = document.createTextNode(id);
  node.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("result").appendChild(node);
}
function select(selector){
  selector.css("background-color","green");
  console.log("youre pressing"+selector.attr("id"));
  selected=selector;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but still it is not working.

Comment: Please review my answer. I made important changes, the code works now

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery click event listeners are added after the click event happens so they are never handled, on the click event you are just binding the click handler. Move the `$().click` outside of the `onclick` and since you are using jQuery selectors for the buttons you can get rid on `onclick`

```js
$(".go_up").click(function() {
  var $current = $(this).closest('li')
  var $previous = $current.prev('li');
  if ($previous.length !== 0) {
    $current.insertBefore($previous);
  }
  return false;
});


$(".go_down").click(function() {
  var $current = $(this).closest('li')
  var $next = $current.next('li');
  if ($next.length !== 0) {
    $current.insertAfter($next);
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class='go_up' style="height:40px;width:40px">&uarr;</button>

<button type="button" class='go_down' style="height:40px;width:40px">&uarr;</button>
<div id="results">
  <div class="boxheader">
    <STRONG>RESULTS</STRONG>
  </div>
  <div class="boxcontent">
    <ul id="result">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but still it is not working.